# Configure Infinispan for Keycloak 17

Tags: keycloak, config, quarkus, infinispan, jgroups

I want to run Keycloak 17 (Quarkus Edition) in HA mode with the provided infinispan. Because we are running Keycloak on serveral stages, I want to specify a infinispan cluster name. As I understood from the documentation I should configure this in the given infinispan config xml ./conf/cache-ispn.xml

I altered

```
     <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
```

to

```
     <transport cluster="myClusterName" lock-timeout="60000"/>
```

After that I ran .\kc.bat build --cache=ispn --cache-config-file=conf/cache-ispn.xml

and started up the server with .\kc.bat start

Sadly the output logging shows this:

```
[org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel `ISPN`
[org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ISPN: [MyHostName-14281|0] (1) [MyHostName-14281]
```

As seen in the logs, the cluster name still is the default "ISPN".

I already consulted the infinispan docs here: https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html

as well as the Keycloak docs:

https://www.keycloak.org/server/caching

https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration

Can anyone help me out? Is this a bug related to Keycloak 17 or am I missing something in the infinispan config?

Full Infinispan Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2019 Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates
  ~ and other contributors as indicated by the @author tags.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:11.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-11.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:11.0">

    <cache-container name="keycloak">
        <transport cluster="myClusterName" lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <local-cache name="realms">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="users">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="sessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="offlineSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="clientSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="loginFailures" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <local-cache name="authorization">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <replicated-cache name="work">
            <expiration lifespan="-1"/>
        </replicated-cache>
        <local-cache name="keys">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <expiration max-idle="3600000"/>
            <memory max-count="1000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="actionTokens" owners="2">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <expiration max-idle="-1" lifespan="-1" interval="300000"/>
            <memory max-count="-1"/>
        </distributed-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

First I copied the cache-ispn.xml to a new file in the same directory and named it cache.xml
I changed the build paramter --cache-config-file=conf/cache-ispn.xml to --cache-config-file=cache.xml
So I just removed the folder specification as Keycloak seems to auto set the config directory to the conf folder.

Comment: that's what it says in the docs: cache-config-file 

"Defines the file from which cache configuration should be loaded from. 

The configuration file is relative to the conf/ directory."

https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config

Comment: @netikras yes I know, I wrote the docs after figuring it out